# How to modify Joomla default search module placeholder value?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

I want to change the default placeholder value of the search field from "Search..." to "XYZ" in Joomla  (default search module). I have modified the `default_form.php` from the directory `/joomla15/components/com_search/views/search/tmpl/` and even removed the following code but it makes no difference on the site:

`<?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD'); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not edit the Joomla core files. If you need to change something, [template overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) is the way to go. However, in this case it shouldn't be needed.

It looks like you're mixing up the *search component* (`components/com_search`) and the *search module* (`modules/mod_search`).

I assume you're using the module, and you can set the placeholder directly in the module settings. Go to **Extensions** -> **Modules** and locate your search module. Open the settings, and edit the field **Box text** to whatever you want the placeholder text to be.

[image: Search module placeholder text]

As you can see from the tooltip, the box will use a string from your language file if the box is left empty. This means you can also [create a language override](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla) in order to change the text.

In that case the string you want to override is `MOD_SEARCH_SEARCHBOX_TEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

To change the placeholder in any form use the following code:

`$this->form->setFieldAttribute( 'name', 'hint', JText::_('KEY_OF_PLACEHOLDER') );`

- **name** : is the fieldname.
- **hint** : placeholder. In joomla core files this is described by attribute       hint.
- **key** : is the key defined in your language file

Comment: i delete some php code from the above mention file but it not works .. can u please mention the file to write the code .

Comment: In default_form.php, there is already `<input type="text" name="searchword" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD'); ?>" `  Did you modify the placeholder attribute?

Comment: yes i remove the code and instead of this code just simple i give place holder value

Comment: you can just add a new value of `COM_SEARCH_SEARCH_KEYWORD` in backend. Go to language manager and create a new key. This will create a overrider of this key and this should work